# Logical symbol for generic logical connectives

Tags: logic

Is there a logical symbol that generically represents a conjunction ($\land$) and a disjunction ($\lor$)? For example, $A$ symbol $B$ would be interpreted either as $A \land B$ or as $A \lor B$. If not, is there any symbol that is used to represent logical connectives in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When summarizing classes of formulas e.g. in proofs by induction on the structure of formulas, I've sometimes seen $\circ$ to stand for an arbitrary binary connective. E.g. "I.S.: (i) $\phi := \neg \psi. \ldots$ (ii) $\phi := \psi \circ \chi. \ldots$", where "$\psi \circ \psi$" is meant to cover the cases $\psi \land \chi, \psi \lor \chi, \psi \to \chi$.
If you want to talk about truth-functional connectives of any arity, you could use the symbol $f$ in prefix notation: "$f\phi_1 \ldots \phi_n$".

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard symbol for this. When an author wants to do this, they'll just introduce their own symbol - I've seen both "$@$" and "$\#$" used in this way. The latter (for arbitrary-arity connectives incidentally) is used in Humberstone's epic tome [The connectives](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/connectives) (see [this review](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi4u4b65LnsAhWEQs0KHX19A44QFjAEegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.uvic.ca%2Findex.php%2Fpir%2Farticle%2Fview%2F12610%2F3800&usg=AOvVaw1Ew7NZ0r_1jyWBmNMvJnAo)), and despite its use elsewhere (e.g. in [geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum)) is probably a bit better choice than "$@$" in this context since "$@$" is used for *actuality* operators in modal logic.

Comment: BTW let me just say that I absolutely love Humberstone's book. It's completely unreasonable, totally bizarre, and wholly wonderful.